# How to pass parameters to POST request in Retrofit - Android

Tags: java, android, api, rest, retrofit2

In my Java based Android app I have to call a POST API in order to save user data. It accepts the following input parameter:
[RequestBody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oye8N.jpg). It then gives the following output: [ResponseBody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btmxk.jpg). How can I perform this with Retrofit?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the point of Retrofit is to send Objects instead of a text body.
from the official docs

```java
@POST("users/new")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
```

you then instantiate your service, with your Retrofit interface, and perform the calls using the interface functions

Comment: Note that in Retrofit Paths must always start with /

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class like this :

```
class Parameters{

 User user;

 class User {
   String username;
   String fullname;
    //more fields, getters and setters..
 }
// getter and setter for user
}
```

Then use retrofit POST by passing an object :

```
@Headers("Content-Type:plain/text; charset=utf-8")
@POST("/postuser")
Call<Response> postData(@Body Parameters params);
```

The Response object has a body() member containing your expected response witch in turn can be also wrapped in an object :

```
class MyResponse{
String status;
String message;
}
```

So you could change your call as follow :

```
@Headers("Content-Type:plain/text; charset=utf-8")
@POST("/postuser")
Call<MyResponse> postData(@Body Parameters params);
```